# How to perform search on my page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, caml-query

I want to create one page or document library where can I perform search.
Suppose user hit the Url like `http://mysite/doclibname/filestartname`that time on my page show only **filestartname** files. How can I do?

Comment: hi,

Please correct me If my understanding is wrong ?
You are asking that you want to create a page where the search results has to show, when a user type the text on search text box and hit the search button or press enter. it has to redirected to your page and you want to display the results in your own page ?

Comment: No I want to give user link like http://mysite/doclibname/filestartname when user click on this i want to show only this document on my page.

Comment: it is not clear still can you please eloberate with little more explanation

Comment: <a href="http://mysite/doclibname/filestartname"> Click Here to open File</a> This is my code when user click on this link open my document library and show only this "filestartname" document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this it might helpful to you.

1. You create a result source in Site search settings for this
   go to Site Settings -> Search -> result source -> create new result source

[image: go to result source]
[image: create new result]

2. type the name of the source and click on "Launch Query builder"

[image: Query builder]

3. Paste the Query which is given here

   {QueryString.MyParameter1} {?owstaxIdMetadataAllTagsInfo:{Tag}} (FileExtension:doc OR FileExtension:docx OR FileExtension:xls OR FileExtension:xlsx OR FileExtension:ppt OR FileExtension:pptx OR FileExtension:pdf) (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
4. click on Ok and Save button to create result source
5. you create a web part page like "Result.aspx" in page library
6. insert search result webpart and go to Webpart Properties and select the result source and click on apply and ok to save the changes

[image: Webpart properties]
[image: Switch mode]
[image: select the result source]

7. after that you can specify url for anchor tag "/Pages/Search.aspx?MyParameter1=Title:filestartname*" with query string.  in your case `<a href="mysite/Pages/Search.aspx?MyParameter1=Title:filestartname*">; Click Here to open File</a>`
8. it automatically filter the result and show based on "filestartname".

Please check and let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Search Preview test screen I get result but when hit he url that time not work.

Comment: If you keep this {QueryString.MyParameter1} and in test result preview you cannot see the results as the query text comes from query string. You just save and pass manually in the url and you can the results on the page directly.

Comment: Yes bro I pass the value in URL but result not display. href="mysite/Pages/Search.aspx?MyParameter1=filestartname* When i pass this URL result display but when i pass url href="mysite/Pages/Search.aspx?MyParameter1=Title:filestartname* that time not display. why?

Comment: May be Title(Title:filestartn‌​ame*) field is blank for all documents in library. you try with other fields present in library which has data like author. author:admin*

Comment: I try other fields but not work this "MyParameter1=Title:filestartn‌​ame" But when I try this MyParameter1=filestartn‌​ame* that time filter

Comment: if you try this MyParameter1=filestartn‌​ame* it search in all fields of data. 
If you need to search especially on one field you need to do in this way only MyParameter1=<fieldname>:filestartn‌​ame* it will work for sure.

what you can do is you can create a managed property and map a crawl property(ex: ows_title) in search schema and do full crawl once then specify this MyParameter1=<managed property name>:filestartn‌​ame*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54111/discussion-between-admin-and-suresh-bolineni).

Comment: Can I set a filter to search must be perform on only particular lib?

Comment: Yes you can specify the Property filter in the result source where you can give the path contain your doc library path eg: {Path:<Library path>}

Comment: can you please tell me how to create  managed property?

Comment: you can refer this link to add managed property 

[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managed-properties-in-search-with-sharepoint-2013-usage/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managed-properties-in-search-with-sharepoint-2013-usage/)

Comment: Hi try to create manages property but not get any luck for fetch document my fields

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you :)